# Where do Teams calendars live?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-teams, microsoft-outlook-365

Do both the Teams and Outlook calendars live in Exchange 365?

If so, how do you pull in Teams calendars into Outlook?

What email address do you use to get them?

Comment: "Do both the Teams and Outlook calendars live in Exchange 365?" - Yes;  "Do both the Teams and Outlook calendars live in Exchange 365?" - Your own; Should be as simply as being invited to those Teams, any events for those Teams, should be shown on your own calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Exchange online server or Exchange on-premises?

As I know, we need to configure the same account in Teams and Outlook so that the calendar will be synced to Outlook. If your mailbox is based on Exchange online, as I know, the calendar in teams and outlook can be synchronized directly without other operations.

If your mailbox is based on Exchange on-premises, please refer to the steps in this article for configuration: [Requirements to get the most out of Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/exchange-teams-interact#requirements-to-create-and-view-meetings-for-mailboxes-hosted-on-premises).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Exchange Online is what we have.

Comment: In your case, you just need to configure the same account in Outlook as in teams, so that you can see the calendar on teams in outlook calendar.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.